# Create SVN repository from few other repo folders

Tags: svn, repository, dump, revision

I've got tough problem.
I've got a few repos, let's say: A B C D
And what I want to do is to import content from these to another new one, let's say repo E.\
Of course with the revision history of all of these repos.
And other thing is that I want to export from A and B only % of content (not all repos).

Can it be done? Any chances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[svnadmin dump](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.dump.html) and [svnadmin load](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html) are your friends here.

Once you have a dump from the old repos, you can filter out the bits you do not want using [svndumpfilter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svndumpfilter.html). You can also edit the dump files to change the paths of the files (carefully) so your old repos will populate the new repo in the organisation you would like.